# How to fix container position even keyboard opens

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to create a Registration page in which I have set all `textfield` in the center and now I want to fix bottom line "Already have an account, Let's play it.." which is `loginLink` object.

```
return Scaffold(
  //resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0, top: 70.0),
                  children: <Widget>[
                  logo,
                  SizedBox(height: 48.0),
                  fullname,
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  email,
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  contactNo,
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  password,
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  c_password,
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  address,
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  signupButton
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: loginLink,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

I want to fix `loginLink` object.

Answer (score 0):

Just warp your top `Container` in `SingleChildScrollView`. By this you also can scroll your link container too while keyboard is open. and set your `ListView` `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`